# wso2 api manager Docker image needs paid subscription

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am planning to use WSO2 API Manager for a client...Planning to use the API Manager Docker image for hosting it..
But it looks like to use API Manager docker image ,I need to have paid subscription once the trial period ends..
https://wso2.com/api-management/install/docker/get-started/ ..the link says 
"  In order to use WSO2 product Docker images, you need an active WSO2 subscription."

Is it like that?
Cant i have the image running in the client premises without any subscription?

Comment: Any answers from the WSO2 team?

Comment: I guess you will receive same the reply which i wrote as they already provide a how-to instructions to build the docker image, so no point in allowing users to access a pre-built images without subscription

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build it yourself using their [official dockerfiles](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim) which hosted on github and then push it to your own registry.

The rest of the dockerfiles for other WSO2 Products can be found under the same [github account](https://github.com/wso2).

The following steps are describing How to build an image and run WSO2 API Manager, taken from this [README.md](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/dockerfiles/ubuntu/apim/README.md) file.

1. Checkout this repository into your local machine using the following Git command.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim.git
   ```

> The local copy of the `dockerfiles/ubuntu/apim` directory will be referred to as `AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME` from this point onwards.

2. Add WSO2 API Manager distribution and MySQL connector to `<AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>/files`.

   - Download [WSO2 API Manager v2.6.0](https://wso2.com/api-management/)
     distribution and extract it to `<AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>/files`.
   - Download [MySQL Connector/J](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j)
     and copy that to `<AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>/files`.
   - Once all of these are in place, it should look as follows:

   ```
   <AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>/files/wso2am-2.6.0/
   <AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>/files/mysql-connector-java-<version>-bin.jar
   ```

   > Please refer to [WSO2 Update Manager documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/WUM300/WSO2+Update+Manager)
   >   in order to obtain latest bug fixes and updates for the product.
3. Build the Docker image.

   - Navigate to `<AM_DOCKERFILE_HOME>` directory. 
     Execute `docker build` command as shown below.
   - `docker build -t wso2am:2.6.0 .`
4. Running the Docker image.

   - `docker run -it -p 9443:9443 wso2am:2.6.0`

     > Here, only port 9443 (HTTPS servlet transport) has been mapped to a Docker host port.
     >   You may map other container service ports, which have been exposed to Docker host ports, as desired.
5. Accessing management console.

   - To access the management console, use the docker host IP and port 9443.
   - `https://<DOCKER_HOST>:9443/carbon`

   > In here,  refers to hostname or IP of the host machine on top of which containers are spawned.

---

How to update configurations

Configurations would lie on the Docker host machine and they can be volume mounted to the container. 
As an example, steps required to change the port offset using `carbon.xml` is as follows.

1. Stop the API Manager container if it's already running. In WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 product distribution, `carbon.xml` configuration file 
   can be found at `<DISTRIBUTION_HOME>/repository/conf`. Copy the file to some suitable location of the host machine, referred to as `<SOURCE_CONFIGS>/carbon.xml` and change the offset value under ports to 1.
2. Grant read permission to `other` users for `<SOURCE_CONFIGS>/carbon.xml`

   ```
   chmod o+r <SOURCE_CONFIGS>/carbon.xml
   ```
3. Run the image by mounting the file to container as follows.

   ```
   docker run \
   -p 9444:9444 \
   --volume <SOURCE_CONFIGS>/carbon.xml:<TARGET_CONFIGS>/carbon.xml \
   wso2am:2.6.0
   ```

   > In here,  refers to /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.6.0/repository/conf folder of the container.

As explained above these steps for ubuntu, for other distributions you can check [the following directory](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/dockerfiles) and then read the README.md file inside

Comment: Could you please elaborate the steps?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the docker images yourself. Follow the instructions given at https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/dockerfiles/ubuntu/apim#how-to-build-an-image-and-run.

Thes caveat is that you will not be getting any bug fixes if you do not have a subscription.